# How to create grid/game board using Visual Basic(windows form)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, grid, game-physics

I am currently undertaking a project where I am creating a game called go. It is a board game of territory, and despite the rules being simple, it is a difficult game to master. If you want to read more about it, click here: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbjOTh_tfXAhVjIcAKHQuxCEgQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGo_(game)&usg=AOvVaw3jJDO24LghMzmB1WUxB2t_

I am using Visual Basic to program this game, more specifically programming it in vb, not C# or any other language, using windows forms as an object orientated game.

I have searched online on how to program this board, but cant find anything that is simple for me to understand(My programming skills aren't too advanced). The main issue is that I will need to record where the users place their pieces, or stones, on the board by clicking on empty spaces, therefore using a 2D array. However, the stones are placed on the **intersections** of the grid,rather than in the spaces between the lines.

I can't find any examples of anyone attempting something similar to this. I can only think of creating/using a picture of the board, import it into windows forms, and overlay with an invisible 2D array when clicked, a black/white stone will appear where clicked. This is another question I have; how to display a piece in forms where clicked.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for helping you _**solve a problem**_, not to point you in the right direction, help you find a resource or write code for you. Do some coding of your own or try to find help elsewhere, and return here when you bump into a more specific problem.

Comment: The most flexible solution would be for you **to DRAW** the lines and pieces in the [Paint()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) of some control such as a Panel.  Simple integer math will tell you which grid lines are closest to where the user clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some starter code using a Panel (Panel1) as the board.  Click on a position multiple times to toggle the state of that position:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const GridSize As Integer = 9 ' small = 9, medium = 13, large = 19
    Private Grid As New List(Of List(Of Boolean?))() ' nullable boolean (black:true, white:false, blank:nothing)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Tan

        ' initialize the grid to all blanks
        For col As Integer = 1 To GridSize
            Dim column As New List(Of Boolean?)
            For row As Integer = 1 To GridSize
                column.Add(Nothing)
            Next
            Grid.Add(column)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.SizeChanged
        Dim pnl As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
        pnl.Invalidate() ' redraw the board whenever it gets resized
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
        Dim pnl As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

        Dim p As Decimal
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim margin As Integer

        ' draw the vertical lines:
        margin = (1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Height
        For col As Integer = 1 To GridSize
            p = col / (GridSize + 1)
            x = p * pnl.Size.Width
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, margin, x, pnl.Size.Height - margin)
        Next

        ' draw the horizontal lines:
        margin = (1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Width
        For row As Integer = 1 To GridSize
            p = row / (GridSize + 1)
            y = p * pnl.Size.Height
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, margin, y, pnl.Size.Width - margin, y)
        Next

        ' draw the pieces:
        For x = 0 To GridSize - 1
            Dim column As List(Of Boolean?) = Grid(x)
            For y = 0 To GridSize - 1
                If Grid(x)(y).HasValue Then
                    Dim clr As Color = If(Grid(x)(y), Color.Black, Color.White)
                    Dim pt As New Point((x + 1) / (GridSize + 1) * pnl.Size.Width, (y + 1) / (GridSize + 1) * pnl.Size.Height)
                    Dim rc As New Rectangle(pt, New Size(1, 1))
                    rc.Inflate((1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Width / 2, (1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Height / 2)
                    Using brsh As New SolidBrush(clr)
                        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brsh, rc)
                    End Using
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.Click
        Dim pnl As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

        ' figure out where the user clicked: min = 0, max = (gridsize -1)
        Dim pt As Point = pnl.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        Dim colWidth As Integer = (1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Width
        Dim rowHeight As Integer = (1 / (GridSize + 1)) * pnl.Size.Height
        Dim gridPosition As New Point(Math.Min(Math.Max((pt.X / colWidth) - 1, 0), GridSize - 1), Math.Min(Math.Max((pt.Y / rowHeight) - 1, 0), GridSize - 1))

        ' now do something with gridPosition: (here we just toggle between black:true, white:false and blank:nothing)
        If Not Grid(gridPosition.X)(gridPosition.Y).HasValue Then
            Grid(gridPosition.X)(gridPosition.Y) = True
        ElseIf Grid(gridPosition.X)(gridPosition.Y) = True Then
            Grid(gridPosition.X)(gridPosition.Y) = False
        Else
            Grid(gridPosition.X)(gridPosition.Y) = Nothing
        End If
        pnl.Invalidate() ' force the board to redraw itself
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample screenshot:
[image: Simple Go Board]